# JavaScript, object to array in specific order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have the below object

```
0:Object
    April:2055.78
    August:2511.18
    December:1833.21
    February:2605.03
    January:1964.85
    July:2337.65
    June:2417.68
    March:1953.51
    May:2203.28
    November:2433.3
    October:1600.67
    September:1874.85
```

I need the values of the object in an array but need it to be ordered by month, Jan-> Dec.

Have tried a couple different methods but still haven't managed to get the correct result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have an array of months and then `result = months.map(m => object[m])`

Comment: _"Have tried a couple different methods but still haven't managed to get the correct result."_ Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: That data should never be an object, if it's supposed to be ordered.  I would be tempted to fix the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple `forEach` and an array of months like this:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var results = [];

months.forEach(function(month){
    results.push(obj[month]);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var obj={
April:2055.78,
August:2511.18,
December:1833.21,
February:2605.03,
January:1964.85,
July:2337.65,
June:2417.68,
March:1953.51,
May:2203.28,
November:2433.3,
October:1600.67,
September:1874.85
};

var results = [];

months.forEach(function(month){
    results.push(obj[month]);
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Why dont you simply map?

Comment: Yes it's just the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj={
April:2055.78,
August:2511.18,
December:1833.21,
February:2605.03,
January:1964.85,
July:2337.65,
June:2417.68,
March:1953.51,
May:2203.28,
November:2433.3,
October:1600.67,
September:1874.85
};

console.log(["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"].map(month=>obj[month]));
```

Theres no other way to let the engine know how to sort (except time expensive date parsing), you  can only tell it the exact month order...

Answer (score 1):

A virtual date can be parsed from the key name with something like `Date.parse(keyname + ' 1, 2000');` (and the date can be sorted on). Not saying this is the best solution for this particular problem, but if you have more objects like this, it might come in handy (although as mentioned in the comments, if the source itself can be altered, that might be preferable)

Example implementation:

```js
let o ={    April:2055.78,    August:2511.18,    December:1833.21,    February:2605.03,    January:1964.85,    July:2337.65,    June:2417.68,    March:1953.51,    May:2203.28,    November:2433.3,    October:1600.67,    September:1874.85};

const getval = k=> Date.parse(k + ' 1, 2000'),
  res = Object.keys(o).sort((k1,k2) => getval(k1) - getval(k2)).map(k=>o[k]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Very smart by using the date object to sort the array!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it: I created an ordered array with the abbreviated month names. Then I looped through that array in order and if the array value was a substring of the object's key, then I pushed that key-value pair into a new object. When you print the object keys, it prints them out in order.

```js
var m = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

var obj = {
April:2055.78,
August:2511.18,
December:1833.21,
February:2605.03,
January:1964.85,
July:2337.65,
June:2417.68,
March:1953.51,
May:2203.28,
November:2433.3,
October:1600.67,
September:1874.85
};

var ordered = {};

for(var i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
 for(key in obj){
   if(key.includes(m[i])){
     ordered[key] = obj[key];
      break;
    }
  }
}

for(key in ordered){
 console.log(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want the months and not the values:

Put your object into a variable (optional)

`var months = {the months object}`

then extract the keys into an array and sort.

`var sortedMonths = Object.keys(months).sort()`

Comment: That won't work! Because will be sort alphabetically!

Comment: Oh shoot. I totally misread.

As far as I know there's no way to guarantee object key order in JS.